# Trying to configure an xml in /resources

Tags: java, spring-boot

Im using eclipse IDE 2020-12 and created this proyect skipping choosing the arquitecture, just added dependencies to the POM. So I was following a Springboot tutorial and get upon the configuration of SampleMapper.xml.

```
    <mapper namespace="com.terceraPrueba.mapper.SampleMapper">

    <select id="getLanguageByUser" resultType="String">
        SELECT USL_LANGUAGE FROM USER_LANGUAGE WHERE USL_USER = #{userName}
    </select>

    <select id="getMessageByLanguage" resultType="String">
        SELECT MSG_DESCRIPTION FROM MESSAGES WHERE MSG_MESSAGE = "welcome" AND MSG_LANGUAGE = #{language}
    </select>

</mapper>
```

I have this xml in `src\main\resources\terceraPrueba\mapper`. I continue the instructions but at the end when I launch the Springboot app, I get upon these errors.

```
2021-02-03 14:01:13.002 ERROR 13384 --- [           main] o.m.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean      : Error while adding the mapper 'interface terceraPrueba.mapper.SampleMapper' to configuration.

org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 59; Document root element "mapper", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
    at org.apache.ibatis.parsing.XPathParser.createDocument(XPathParser.java:259) ~[mybatis-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.ibatis.parsing.XPathParser.<init>(XPathParser.java:125) ~[mybatis-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.<init>(XMLMapperBuilder.java:78) ~[mybatis-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.<init>(XMLMapperBuilder.java:73) ~[mybatis-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.annotation.MapperAnnotationBuilder.loadXmlResource(MapperAnnotationBuilder.java:168) ~[mybatis-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.annotation.MapperAnnotationBuilder.parse(MapperAnnotationBuilder.java:120) ~[mybatis-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperRegistry.addMapper(MapperRegistry.java:72) ~[mybatis-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.addMapper(Configuration.java:706) ~[mybatis-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean.checkDaoConfig(MapperFactoryBean.java:81) ~[mybatis-spring-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet(DaoSupport.java:44) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1148) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1051) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at terceraPrueba.Application.main(Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document root element "mapper", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:135) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(XMLDTDValidator.java:1539) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1806) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:728) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1406) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1292) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3078) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:836) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:541) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:246) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.parsing.XPathParser.createDocument(XPathParser.java:257) ~[mybatis-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    ... 41 common frames omitted

2021-02-03 14:01:13.003  WARN 13384 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sampleRepository' defined in file [C:\Users\amarroqu\Documents\PruebasSpringBoot\terceraPrueba\target\classes\terceraPrueba\repository\SampleRepository.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sampleMapper' defined in file [C:\Users\amarroqu\Documents\PruebasSpringBoot\terceraPrueba\target\classes\terceraPrueba\mapper\SampleMapper.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 59; Document root element "mapper", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
2021-02-03 14:01:13.005  INFO 13384 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2021-02-03 14:01:13.022  INFO 13384 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-02-03 14:01:13.026 ERROR 13384 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sampleRepository' defined in file [C:\Users\amarroqu\Documents\PruebasSpringBoot\terceraPrueba\target\classes\terceraPrueba\repository\SampleRepository.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sampleMapper' defined in file [C:\Users\amarroqu\Documents\PruebasSpringBoot\terceraPrueba\target\classes\terceraPrueba\mapper\SampleMapper.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 59; Document root element "mapper", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1148) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1051) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at terceraPrueba.Application.main(Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sampleMapper' defined in file [C:\Users\amarroqu\Documents\PruebasSpringBoot\terceraPrueba\target\classes\terceraPrueba\mapper\SampleMapper.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 59; Document root element "mapper", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 59; Document root element "mapper", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
    at org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean.checkDaoConfig(MapperFactoryBean.java:84) ~[mybatis-spring-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet(DaoSupport.java:44) ~[spring-tx-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 59; Document root element "mapper", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
    at org.apache.ibatis.parsing.XPathParser.createDocument(XPathParser.java:259) ~[mybatis-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.ibatis.parsing.XPathParser.<init>(XPathParser.java:125) ~[mybatis-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.<init>(XMLMapperBuilder.java:78) ~[mybatis-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.<init>(XMLMapperBuilder.java:73) ~[mybatis-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.annotation.MapperAnnotationBuilder.loadXmlResource(MapperAnnotationBuilder.java:168) ~[mybatis-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.annotation.MapperAnnotationBuilder.parse(MapperAnnotationBuilder.java:120) ~[mybatis-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperRegistry.addMapper(MapperRegistry.java:72) ~[mybatis-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.addMapper(Configuration.java:706) ~[mybatis-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean.checkDaoConfig(MapperFactoryBean.java:81) ~[mybatis-spring-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document root element "mapper", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:135) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(XMLDTDValidator.java:1539) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1806) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:728) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1406) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1292) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3078) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:836) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:541) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:246) ~[na:na]
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.parsing.XPathParser.createDocument(XPathParser.java:257) ~[mybatis-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

For what I have searched, I have to put the dtd config in the top of the SampleMapper.xml, but when ever I do that I get erros in the whole xml.

```
 <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"   "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.terceraPrueba.mapper.SampleMapper">

    <select id="getLanguageByUser" resultType="String">
        SELECT USL_LANGUAGE FROM USER_LANGUAGE WHERE USL_USER = #{userName}
    </select>

    <select id="getMessageByLanguage" resultType="String">
        SELECT MSG_DESCRIPTION FROM MESSAGES WHERE MSG_MESSAGE = "welcome" AND MSG_LANGUAGE = #{language}
    </select>

</mapper>
```

So yeah, I'm kinda stuck. I'm sure it's a stupid error, but can figure what is wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At least that problem is solved (?) I just put the SampleMapper.xml in the same package where the SampleMapper.java is.